# Weird mysqldump behaviour

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use mysqldump on a remote host. 
My local IP is **111.111.111.111**, and the remote IP is **222.222.222.222**
I run this command:

```
mysqldump --host=222.222.222.222 -u user test_db
```

This doesn't work as what I get back this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'111.111.111.111' (using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

So instead of connecting to the remote server, mysqldump tries to connect to the localhost.

Also, I noticed that when I replace the remote IP with another one, it tries to connect to that one.

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote host answers you that access denied for the 'user'@'111.111.111.111'

Since you are connecting from that 111.111.111.111 host. On the remote host 222.222.222.222 you need to create the grants for 'user'@'111.111.111.111' to be able to connect from 111.111.111.111

So the behavior is quite standard actually. + you need to specify password "-p mypass"

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` doesn't try to connect to localhost. MySQL distinguish users like 'name'@'host-from-where-that-user-connects'

You probably need to provide password as `mysqldump` says.